# join two dictionary values based on key and check condition on value field

Tags: c#, linq

How to merge two dictionay where dictionary structure is

**First dictionary:**

```
Key: Key1  
value: {100,Name1,Address1, Address2, Address3, Address4, Address5}  
       {100,Name2,Address1, Address2, Address3, Address4, Address5}
```

**Second dictionary:**

```
Key: Key1  
value: {100,Name1,Field1, Field2, Field3, Field4, Field5}   
       {101,Name1,Field1, Field2, Field3, Field4, Field5}
```

Here i have to check for value field which is list Of string array. in that above case in both dictionary we have common value is 100 and name1 so.
Expected Result:

```
Key: Key1  
value: {100,Name1,Address1, Address2, Address3, Address4, Address5,Field1, Field2, Field3, Field4, Field5}
```

Comment: hi dictionary structure is new dictionary<string,list<string[]>>()

Comment: I can see task, but I don't see what problem you have with your attempt to solve this task. Looks like there is no problem

Comment: hi i can do it with concate method when i have to iterate only one key but i am not sure how to proceed when i have check for values field

Comment: Please show your attempt with concatenate method

Comment: Hi I posted my approach where I am able to get desired output.

Comment: You should edit your question instead of adding answers

Answer (score 0):

Hi below is my approach.                                                                                                              var final = new Dictionary>();

foreach (var item in _record1) 
            { 
                var key = item.Key;

```
            List<string[]> first = _record1[key]; 
            List<string[]> second = _record2[key]; 

            foreach (var a in first) 
            { 
                foreach (var b in second) 
                { 
                    if (a[0] == b[0] && a[1] == b[1]) 
                    { 
                        // some operation 
                        // add items to final                           
                    } 
                } 
            } 
        }
```

i am able to get desired result but i am looking for some good approach.